# How to handle many time consuming tasks in java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a project with a thread pool of limited size, which handles diagnosis tasks polled from a queue.

Some of the task types require the thread to be paused for many hours in different steps in order to wait for data to be generated, so the diagnosis can be conituned.

This brings a big problem, if the tasks in the thread pool are all paused, new tasks will be blocked. However, those tasks may not need to be paused for data generation and can be diagnosed immediately.

Increasing the thread pool size is not a good option in my opition, since the task number can be large, so I'm wondering if there is any good way to handle this problem in java. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** On non-virtualizes Operating Systems you can have 2000-10000 Threads without problems. Depends on the RAM and the OS config. So usually it's not a problem.

Write a simple app that allocates new Threads until that step throws an exception.

**2)** You could also create a ThreadPool that automatically adjusts its size:

```
newThreadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(basePoolSize, maxPoolSize, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
```

**3)** So now to finally actually answer your question:

- before the tasks go into *sleep mode*
- - pass that working state data (probably some data state object) to a **TODO list** (maybe a `PriorityQueue` or `LinkedBlockingList` or just an `ArrayList`, depending on how you want to handle the next step)
- - leave the `run()` method via `return;` or some other means, so that you will not get stuck in the waiting/blocking phase, but free the thread to return to the executor pool and pick up new tasks
- now, have a thread that either
- - polls if data for the tasks in the **TODO list** has become available
- - or reacts to certain events
- ... to know when to continue
- now check if the data for the task is in workable state.
- - if NOT, then just leave or re-add to **TODO list**
- - if YES, either
- - - re-queue this task with the old executor pool, if feasible
- - - or queue it into another executor pool that is specialized in resuming those tasks

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Since this application is running on a server shared by many others, I think a TODO list will be a good way to try. Thanks again for your fast and helpful reply :D